# Include a simple val in sbt build files from global.sbt

Tags: sbt

I wish to set my version numbers externally across several `build.sbt` files through a single include file.

Within build.sbt I can do this

```scala
val base = "1.1"

version := base + ".8-SNAPSHOT"
```

This works fine as a first step.

According the the online help I should be able to create a file `global.sbt` in my `~/.sbt/0.13` folder

I created the file `global.sbt` with single line

```scala
val base = "1.1"
```

and removed the corresponding line from `build.sbt`

But when I start up my sbt I get "error: not found: value base"

So either it's not finding the global sbt or this form of global setting doesn't work.

Any suggestions as to how I can resolve this?

Can I make an explicit include command in my build.sbt files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems from your test that `val`s in global `~/.sbt/0.13/*.sbt` files don't propagate to local `*.sbt` files.

Here's a setup that works:

**~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/VersionBasePlugin.scala**

```scala
import sbt._, Keys._

object VersionBasePlugin extends AutoPlugin {
  override def requires = plugins.CorePlugin
  override def trigger = allRequirements

  object autoImport {
    val versionBase = settingKey[String]("version base")
  }
  import autoImport._

  override def projectSettings = Seq(versionBase := "1.1")
}
```

and then in your `build.sbt`:

```scala
version := (versionBase.value + ".8-SNAPSHOT")
```

Does that work for you?